# How to reliably launch/switch to a different window

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a background service that sometimes needs to launch other application from a low level keyboard hook.

The issue is that if the launched app has a window, the window will flash but it won't be brought into the foreground.

I'm pretty sure the issue is as described in this [SetForegroundWindow function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx) remark:

> An application cannot force a window to the foreground while the user is working with another window. Instead, Windows flashes the taskbar button of the window to notify the user.

Does anyone know what exactly it means when a user is 'working with another window' ? E.g., how long must the inactivity be so it doesn't qualify as 'working' anymore? If my hook suppresses events, does that still qualify as working or not?

Clarification : The service doesn't interrupt user when it tries to switch to other application. My service is basically replacement for alt+tab but in a specialized way.

Comment: There is no timeout, as you imply. If a user works with a window, that is the foreground window, until the user decides to bring another window to the foreground, or the foreground thread calls `SetForegroundWindow`.

Comment: Do you think it's like this or you know it's somewhere documented ? I can't find anything on MSDN but I building on assumptions isn't very reliable way ... . The app needs to work reliably. Thanks

Comment: @Bohus: why does your service require interrupting the user? This is exactly the kind of situation that Windows tries to avoid. A background process needs cooperation from a foreground process to force a window to the foreground. See `AllowSetForegroundWindow()`. You are not going to get that cooperation from apps you didn't write. You may have to inject code remotely into the foreground process, for instance. Dont do it. Rethink your design. What apps are you launching that are so important that they can't wait their turn for focus?

Comment: Services run in an isolated session, separate from user processes, I can't remember offhand but there may be some caveats trying to access a user session window from a service.

Comment: @kvr: the OP doesn't explicitly state how the service is launching processes, but it is well known that a service can use `CreateProcessAsUser()` to launch processes in user sessions. That doesn't change the rules that `SetForegroundWindow()` enforces.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I agree

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I've added clarification into the question to answer your question.

Comment: @Bohus "*The service doesn't interrupt user when it tries to switch to other application. My service is basically replacement for alt+tab but in a specialized way*" - but Windows doesn't know that. All it knows is that some window already has focus, and you are launching a new process that is trying to gain focus when it is not allowed to have focus. That is why the new process flashes instead.